# How to clear a form in an ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html template with a reusable modal that gets ng-included like this:

myPartial.html

```
... SOME HTML ...
<ng-include src="'form.html'"></ng-include>
```

modal.html

```
...
<form>
  <input ng-model="comment.value" />
  <button type="submit" ng-click="save(comment.value)" />
</form>
...
```

What is the best way to clear the form -- particularly from the controller if possible. I'd like to clear the form from my `save()` method after a successful http call, but since ng-include creates it's own scope, i'm not sure how to do this.

Here's a plunker to show my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/zkxZOZr3f7sHJZfCiuoT?p=preview

If you take the contents of form.html and put them directly into index.html it works just fine.

Comment: Please setup a demo. It is quite straightforward to achieve

Comment: I edited the question with a plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Just initialize the comment instance in your controller and update the correct value in save. I believe the behaviour your experiencing is called "prototypal inheritance" and you can read about it at [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). This is not exclusive to AngularJS btw, but can be found in regular JavaScript as well.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('appcontroller', function($scope) {

  // create comment
  $scope.comment = { value: 'test' };
  $scope.save = function(value) {
    console.log('in here ');

    // and update comment.value, not comment.
    $scope.comment.value = null;
  };
});
```

I updated your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0p1zMTdhYf0q56mDeZC7?p=preview).

Comment: Ahh i also figured out that I was trying to explicitly set it as you suggest except I was setting it to null and that doesn't work so I just set it initially to an empty object and it works then.